# Why does cholesky factorization fail for pascal matrices of big size?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I want to perform cholesky factorization for pascal matrix of size 50. The values become too large so `scipy.linalg.pascal` returns matrix of `object` type.

```
A_scipy = scipy.linalg.pascal(50)
A_scipy.dtype
>dtype('O')
```

If construct it by hand:

```
def construct_pascal_triangle(n):
    L = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.float64)
    L[:, 0] = 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            L[i][j] = L[i-1][j] + L[i-1][j-1]
    return L
L = construct_pascal_triangle(n)
A = L @ L.T
```

then it differs from `A_scipy`. I assume that `np.float64` can't handle it as well, so when I turned dtype to `object` in function `construct_pascal_triangle`, `A` and `A_scipy` coincided. `np.linalg.cholesky` can't handle the `object` type matrix. So I wrote own function

```
def cholesky(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    M = A.copy()
    L = np.zeros_like(A)
    for i in range(n):
        L[i, i] = M[i, i] ** 0.5
        L[i, i + 1:] = M[i, i + 1:] / L[i, i]
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            M[j, j:] = M[j, j:] - L[i, j] * L[i, j:]
```

But it also fails because `M[i, i]` becomes negative at some point. I wonder why that is happening. Pascal matrices are positive definite for any size so cholesky factorization always exists. Is it the problem with type already and numbers are so big that even object can't handle them? Or this is something else?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think that `M[i,i] ** 0.5` does when applied to a long integer?

If you discover that it converts the result to nearest float64, then you get an explanation for inexactness...

float64 uses inexact arithmetic (the result of arithmetic operations have to be rounded to nearest float64).

Mixing numbers with exact arithmetic (at least for + - *) and inexact arithmetic leads to inexact arithmetic. So this `**` step looses the extra precision.

Even if `M[i,i] ** 0.5` itself is an exact operation (it should be for n=50), the following operations like `L[i, j] * L[i, j:]` may exceed the 53bits precision of float64 and loose exactness.

You would have to find (or write) a sqrt version which preserve the integer result when the square root is an exact integer. (Squeak Smalltalk sqrt does that for example).